# Using selenium chromedriver with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have installed python 2.7 and pip in my environment variables. I have also installed selenium in my python path. Now I am trying to create a selenium script using PyCharm. My simple code is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Path_to_driver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)

driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("abc@abc.com")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys("abcd")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()

time.sleep(4)

driver.quit()
```

I am getting below error when I run the code. I have triple checked webdriver path etc. and I also tried running it from python IDLE. But I am getting error as shown below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/test/Test/test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Path_to_driver\chromedriver.exe")
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I read many articles on internet, but no solution seems to be solving my problem.

Comment: If that is a real password, you should probably change it ASAP

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce OMG bro thanks for pointing it out. It could have been a blunder!

Answer (score 1):

remove the path when you instantiate the webdriver. if it's in your path it will find it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)
```

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\arpit\automation\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

...implies that the *Python Script* was unable to access the **webdriver** module.

As per the best practices you need to follow the following points :

- Always specify the *Key* `executable_path` along with the *Value* as the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* through single back slash i.e. `\` within single quotes i.e. `'.....'` along with the raw i.e. `r` switch as follows :

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\arpit\automation\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
  ```
- Try to execute your `@Tests` as a *non-root* user.

Answer (score 0):

No need to explicitly provide the driver path in your code. just put the driver path in path environment variable as well. Python will automatically detect it.

Further, piece of advice always try and work in a virtual environment so that project installation does not interfere with global libraries.

python libraries like virtualenv can be used for this purpose.

code snippet :-

```
def main():

    global driver

   # Create a instance of Chrome browser

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

  call your function here

  # exit the browser

   driver.quit(
```

Comment: Why would you use a global variable though?

Comment: so that you can use the driver variable in your function as well.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, [global variables should be avoided](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/using_the_global_statement.html#using-the-global-statement) and there is no need to use one here.

Comment: yeah you can say in a way but in my usecase it was satisfying the need. nevertheless, you can declare on top a you wish. 

Hope the solution worked for you.

Comment: Unnecessary global variable aside, your solution doesn't even run. Also, I didn't ask the question.